# Android Creating Array of widgets in the XML and reading in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-emulator, android-widget

In my project i have several TextBoxes which i have to fill dynmically. I have the values to be filled in a list, and i want to apply setText to the text boxes at the time of iterating list.
Is this possible to have the name of widget as array type like textbox[1], textbox[2]....... Here in the xml it do not give any error but in the activity class while reading it gives error,

```
findViewById(R.id.textbox[1]    //textbox cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Is there any other way of manipulating this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would try using reflection:

```
for(int i = 0; condition;i++){
    try {
        int id = (Integer) R.id.class.getField("textbox"+i).get(null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        textView.setText("i th text from your list");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can make your own array of textboxs...

```
    ArrayList<TextBox> textbox = new new ArrayList<TextBox>();
    textbox.add((TextBox)findViewById(R.id.textbox1);  
    textbox.add((TextBox)findViewById(R.id.textbox2);
```

then use it like: textbox[1]

Comment: add method not works with TextView. pls elaborate with code with details. thanks.

Comment: sudar's answer might be better :)

Comment: Yes Amitay, problem resolved with sundar's post. Thanks for ur help.