# How to load multiple drawables from id using a loop?

Tags: android, resources

Must be a way looping through this code:

```
private void loadSprites() {
    this.sprites[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom01);
    this.sprites[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom02);
    this.sprites[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom03);
    this.sprites[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom04);
    this.sprites[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom05);
    this.sprites[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom06);
    this.sprites[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_boom07);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where you want to display these image?? In listview or GridView? What?

Comment: you can use reflection something as from my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441419/android-creating-array-of-widgets-in-the-xml-and-reading-in-activity/7441598#7441598

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar it really does not mater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your images in the assets folder. From their you can access them via their file name. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html.

Comment: Good! AssetManager was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I am understand your question, you want something like,

```
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.ic_boom01,R.drawable.ic_boom02,R.drawable.ic_boom03,R.drawable.ic_boom04,R.drawable.ic_boom05,R.drawable.ic_boom06,R.drawable.ic_boom07}


private void loadSprites() {
for(int i=0; i<this.sprites.length; i++)
    this.sprites[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I would rather not hard code the R.drawable.ic_boom IDs either. Thanks heaps though.

Comment: Thanks again, I was looking for an elegant solution like the AssetManager. I'm very grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below code for that.

First make int array

```
int[] mImgArray = { R.drawable.ic_boom01, R.drawable.ic_boom02,
            R.drawable.ic_boom03, R.drawable.ic_boom04, R.drawable.ic_boom05,
            R.drawable.ic_boom06, R.drawable.ic_boom07 };
```

or Set this Image to ImageView using below code

```
mImgView1.setImageResource(mImgArray[0]);
```

And you can convert this image directly to bitmap and store into bitmap array using below code.

```
Bitmap mBmpArray=new Bitmap[mImgArray.length];
for(int i=0; i<mImgArray.length; i++)
    mBmpArray[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImgArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, that is what I try to avoid hardcode lots of IDs in an array.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
//Bitmap of images for fly asset
     private Bitmap fly[] = new Bitmap[8];
    
    //Initialize array of images
    for(int i = 0; i < fly.length; i++){
                this.fly[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("fly_frame" + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName() ) );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in a simple for loop.. and start from the first id and increment it by 1 at each loop.. though I don't recommend you to do this..